# Hazelcast Cache timing issue

Tags: hazelcast, spring-cache, hazelcast-imap

I am facing issue regarding hazelcast cache.The hazelcast cache taking around 5 sec.
Currently i am using the hazelcast with springboot application.I cached a method at service level in hazelcast. Cache data size is in in kb. I am calling this service method via my controller.Time taken for returning data from cache is 5 sec which is very high.I think so it should be in milliseconds.If your data is cached then it should get processed in milliseconds.

Here is my controller and service:

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/statusSummaryFilters", produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)               
 public ResponseEntity<StatusSummaryDataResource> getStatusSummaryData(@RequestParam Long epochTime)              
 {
return ResponseEntity.ok(statusSummaryService.getCachedStatusSummaryData(epochTime));
   }

**StatusSummaryService:**

// This is the service method from where i returned the cached data.Data is in form of list of objects.Nearly around 36000 objects of StatusSummaryDto.

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Cacheable(value = Constants.CACHE_STATUS_SUMMARY_DATA,  sync = true)
    public List<StatusSummaryDto> getCachedStatusSummaryData(Long endDateEpochTime) { 
}
```

**Hazelcast Configuration:**

```
package com.hns.services.restapi.config;
import com.hazelcast.config.Config;
import com.hazelcast.config.EvictionPolicy;
import com.hazelcast.config.MapConfig;
import com.hazelcast.config.MaxSizeConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import static com.hns.services.restapi.constants.Constants.*;

@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {
    private static final Integer TTL_SECS = 3600;

    @Bean
    public Config hazelcastConfig() {
        return new Config().setInstanceName("hazelcast-instance-parteek").setProperty("hazelcast.initial.min.cluster.size","1")

                .addMapConfig(new MapConfig().setName(CACHE_STATUS_SUMMARY_DATA)
                        .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(100, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE))
                        .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                        .setTimeToLiveSeconds(TTL_SECS));         
    }
}
```

Please tell me if i am doing something wrong or not.If i am missing something in hazelcast configuration please let me know about it so i can fix it.

Comment: Try changing `List<StatusSummaryDto> getCachedStatusSummaryData` to `Long getCachedStatiusSummaryData`. Try without `sync=true`. Just as explorations. Do they make any different to the timings ?

Comment: It sounds like the Hazelcast cache configuration is not picked up. Please check your project for these common configuration pitfalls: 1. Is your application annotated with `@EnableCaching`? 2. Is the `hazelcast-spring` artifact in your dependencies?

Comment: @user3318861 any luck ? Is there a time difference if you call it twice ? That would be some indication if caching annotation is being used or ignored